# Eclipse Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I just started java and I get this error on this code which should work..

The error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Distance2.main(Distance2.java:8)
```

The code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Distance2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int v1 = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
        int v2 = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );

        System.out.println(Math.abs(v1 - v2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you pass in any arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass at least two argument which you should be integer otherwise it will throw parsing exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments to the program.
and before using the values its highly recommended to check for the size of the args array.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the program in using command prompt as java Distance2 2 5;   or for Eclipse you jump to step 6 of this url - > [eclipse-arguments](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/cmd-line-args/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse-ide/)

Answer (score 0):

You must not have passed any argument.

To play safe, you can put your code in a try/catch block.

Cheers

Comment: But this is the model answer given by the teachers.. but I cannot run it on my PC

Comment: @user1733324 In order to pass arguments, you need to pass them via the command prompt. If you are simply running it via some software like netbeans, eclipse, etc. you cannot pass those arguments.

Comment: @user1733324 The args[] is a string array which contains the inputs you specify from the command line. You are missing that, hence the exception.